# how to set images with specific width,height and css in phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I am developing a simple project in phalcon framework step by step, but stuck while setting images with specific heights and widths and css classes.

How do I do this in phalcon?

```
<img src="images/logo.png" style=" margin-top:20px; margin-left:10px; "width="265" height="54">
```

My Bad. sorry no class but the image properties

```
<div class="col-md-6 logo"><img src="images/logo.png" style=" margin-top:20px; margin-left:10px; "width="265" height="54"></div>
```

Comment: i used this <?php echo $this->tag->image("img/hello.gif"); ?> but no styles

Comment: Show us your css code and which classes the image uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer i found is

```
echo \Phalcon\Tag::image(array(
        "images/logo.png",
        "alt" => "Your image",
        'style' => 'width:100px;height:200px;margin-top:20px; margin-left:10px',
    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using the volt template engine

```
{{ image("images/logo.png", "class": "col-md-6 logo") }}
```

if you are using phtml template

```
$this->tag->image(array("images/logo.png","class" => "col-md-6 logo"));
```